# Navigationbar with searchbar will not show large title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` with a `UINavigationController` as the masterviewcontroller. This `UINavigationController` has a `UICollectionViewController` as its rootViewController. In the `UICollectionViewController`, I have set the following parameters:

```
self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.collectionView.bounces = YES;
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;

UISearchController *sc = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.navigationItem.searchController = sc;
```

The `UISearchBar` does show up in the navigationBar, but when I launch the app the navbar is collapsed to the small title. It's only when I drag the view downwards that the large title and the search bar appear.

Where I expect the view to launch like this

[image]

it actually launches like this

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Which iOS version you are running for this style of navigationbar ?

Comment: iOS 11 is the version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set `preferLargeTitles` to `true` in your UINavigationBar; either in code or in the Storyboard file.

Put this in your viewDidLoad.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```